# How do you startup windows agents/slaves on aws using jenkins ec2 plugin

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-pipeline, jnlp, ec2-ami

I set up an AWS Windows AMI that was configured to run as a slave using JNLP connection.  When the instance is running slave/agent is recognized by the jenkins master and it works in static mode.  If I use this AMI with EC2 Jenkins plugin to spawn Windows slaves/agents  on the fly it seems to have a problem connecting a slave and instead makes static slave active.  JNLP connection created a unique secret key, which I baked into an AMI so I assume that is why its connecting to the static slave instead of spinning new ones based on the AMI. I think I need to figure out the way to generate JNLP secret key on the master and pass it to the agent/slave during spawning, but I have trouble doing this.  Did anybody figure out the way to fire off Window slaves with EC2 plugin using this or other methods.  Thank you very much for your help!